# Plot a figure in which there is an image that moves and rotates

Tags: matlab

I am going to plot a dynamic image (moving, rotating) within a MATLAB figure. How can I do that?

I know that for embedding an image in MATLAB i should use this code:

> I = imread('image.jpg');
>
> figure;
>
> hold on;
>
> image([-1 1],[1 -1],I);

How to draw the image by indicating its center position and its scale. How to move / rotate it?

Also, is there a way to plot the object with its background transparent?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to start with,

This is the simplified code in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717775/animate-text-in-matlab).

```
load topo
n = size(topomap1,1);
topo = (topo - min(topo(:))) ./ range(topo(:));
I = ind2rgb(round(topo*(n-1)+1), topomap1);
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(n);
for i = 1 : n
    [az,el,r] = cart2sph(X,Y,Z);
    az = az + 2 / n * pi;
    [X,Y,Z] = sph2cart(az,el,r);
    warp(X,Y,Z,I)
    axis equal off
    pause(.1)
end
```

[image]

You can change `I` to any image, like `I = imread('peppers.png');`

Also you can change the surface to any (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27056373/save-animated-warp-as-a-gif-file-in-matlab)).